# Problem when upgrading graphql-js from 14.1.1 to 14.3.0

Tags: graphql-js, graphql-tools

i'm just upgrade `graphql-js` from version `14.1.1` to `14.3.0` and then my whole test fail

after checking my code i found that problem is at resolver on interface type that i expect third parameter was context as code below

`__resolveType(obj, args, context, info) {...}`

but on `graphql-js` version `14.3.0` i found that context is change to second position

i tried to find which commit is reference to this problem but found nothing
can someone explain me how this problem happend or post a commit or changelog detail thanks

Comment: There is no `__resolveType` in GraphQL.js. This is something that's specific to Apollo's `graphql-tools`.

Comment: @DanielRearden thanks for the answer, now i found that i got the missing point the problem is not context args position but i expect args length of __resolveType is 3 but got 4 on graphql 14.3.0

Comment: ps. i understand that __resolveType is not in graphql-js but in graphql-tools, i have no idea why only upgrading graphql-js make this happend, are you have any suggestion?

Comment: i found it!, the change in graphql-js made my code fail because of 14.3.0 GraphQLTypeResolver has abstractType declared thanks for help @DanielRearden